# Problems with gpx in Qgis after GPSmap64s update

Tags: qgis, gpx, garmin

After an update of a Garmin GPSmap64s via Garminexpress the daily gpx tracks (e.b. 2021-11-08) are not displayed in Qgis 3.20, but only when I zoom in (between 1:10000 and 1:25000, >1:25000 works fine, scale dependent visibility not active). The identify tool responds with 'No features at this position'(zoom to layer works fine).

When I load the 'Current' track (kind of working track for the day) it works fine, visibility & identify. Even after saving the gpx to a shape or geopackage the problem is the same.
Same problems with Qgis 3.8

Does anybody know the reason and a solution?

**Edit**: Problem persists even in print composer: when zoom in, in the print composer the track disappears.

In Garmin Basecamp gpx: no problem
In Google Earth kml: no problem
In Qgis kml: same problem

I tried several ways of 'save as' to different formats, in Qgis the layer always disappears and identify tool does not found a feature, in other apps in works fine. Only with track files recorded after update.

File structure in Notepad++ seems ok. I am really lost at this point...

Sample files:
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5ee7900a0cf9593938e7016af2b43cf420211110102732/f799057dc2856dfcf825bb4182eeda0520211110102755/43c6b9

11-06 should work fine
11-09 shows the problems

Comment: can anybody reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "2021-11-09 08.15.26 Tag.gpx" has, near the end, a "trkseg" with only 1 "trkpt": i.e. a segment with only 1 vertex, while a segment needs at least 2 vertex.

Just removing

```
<trkseg><trkpt lat="48.2036112528" lon="13.0986352824"><ele>357.78</ele><time>2021-11-10T07:29:54Z</time></trkpt></trkseg>
```

near the end of the file will fix the issue.

Otherwise you can also fix the issue using the QGIS Processing algorithm "Multipart to singleparts" with the "tracks" layer as input. The "Single parts" layer created by the algorithm will contain 1 feature for each "trkseg": in your case you can then remove the third feature (Feature ID: 3) which is an invalid LineString with only 1 vertex.

You can also fix the issue importing the track using the "GPS Tools" core plugin.

Comment: thanks! never noticed GPS-Tools, always used load vector layer